# d3.conventions not a function at script.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

NY Times graphics editor Adam pearce recently released a raw version of the NY Times "You draw it"-Code using D3. When trying to reuse it, I am getting this error message:

"d3.conventions is not a function at script.js".

This is the code:

## index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<body></body>

<script src='d3v4.js'></script>
<script src='_script.js'></script>
```

## script.js

```js
 var data = [
      {"year": 2001,    "debt": 31.4},
      {"year": 2002,    "debt": 32.6},
      {"year": 2003,    "debt": 34.5},
      {"year": 2004,    "debt": 35.5},
      {"year": 2005,    "debt": 35.6},
      {"year": 2006,    "debt": 35.3},
      {"year": 2007,    "debt": 35.2},
      {"year": 2008,    "debt": 39.3},
      {"year": 2009,    "debt": 52.3},
      {"year": 2010,    "debt": 60.9},
      {"year": 2011,    "debt": 65.9},
      {"year": 2012,    "debt": 70.4},
      {"year": 2013,    "debt": 72.6},
      {"year": 2014,    "debt": 74.4},
      {"year": 2015,    "debt": 73.6},
    ]
    
    var ƒ = d3.f
    
    var sel = d3.select('body').html('')
    var c = d3.conventions({
      parentSel: sel, 
      totalWidth: sel.node().offsetWidth, 
      height: 400, 
      margin: {left: 50, right: 50, top: 30, bottom: 30}
    })
```

Where can I find d3.conventions? Thanks a lot for your help!

Full code can be found here: https://bl.ocks.org/1wheel/07d9040c3422dac16bd5be741433ff1e

Comment: Read this: https://github.com/1wheel/d3-starterkit

Answer (score -1):

As code **exports.conventions = conventions;** not available in **d3v4.js** and in order to run d3 conventions you have to import d3 conventions module.

**https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-convention**